# Prioritize specific long-running operation

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo collection with a little under 2 million documents in it, and I have a query that I wish to run that will delete around 700.000 of them, based on a Date-field.

The remove query looks something like this:

```
db.collection.remove({'timestamp': { $lt: ISODate('XXXXX') }})
```

The exact date is not important in this case, the syntax is correct and I know it will work. However, I also know it's going to take forever (last time we did something similar it took a little under 2 hours).

There is another process inserting and updating records at the same time that I cannot stop. However, as long as those insertions/updates "eventually" get executed, I don't mind them being deferred.

My question is: Is there any way to set the priority of a specific query / operation so that it runs faster / before all the queries sent afterwards? In this case, I assume mongo has to do a lot of swapping data in and out of the database which is not helping performance.

Comment: A few ideas: marking as deleted, and then reuse the deleted records (rather than actually removing); secondary collection of documents indicating whether a primary doc is active/deleted (minimizing amount of data that needs to be paged).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether the priority can be fine-tuned, so there might be a better answer.

A simple workaround might be what is suggested in the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/delete/):

> **Note**: For large deletion operations it may be more effect [sic] to copy the documents that you want to save to a new collection and then use `drop()` on the original collection.

Another approach is to write a simple script that fetches e.g. 500 elements and then deletes them using `$in`. You can add some kind of `sleep()` to throttle the deletion process. This was [recommended in the newsgroup](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/WbPWMLThZac).

If you will encounter this problem in the future, you might want to

- Use a day-by-day collection so you can simply drop the entire collection once data becomes old enough (this makes aggregation harder), **or**
- use a [TTL-Collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) where items will time out automatically and don't need to be deleted in a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

If your application needs to delete data older than a certain amount of time i suggest using [TTL indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/). Ex (from the mongodb site):

```
db.log.events.ensureIndex( { "status": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

This works like a capped collection, except data is deleted by time. The biggest win for you is that it works in a background thread, your inserts/updates will be mostly unhurt. I use this technique on a SaaS based product in production, works like a charm.

This may not be your use-case, but i hope that helped.

Comment: Not a bad suggestions, but we are using Mongodb 2.0 (this is 2.2+) and I need the data gone right away and not after a certain threshold. Will put it in my toolbox instead :)

Comment: Hmm. In that case I suggest indexing timestamp, then doing a find and looping over the results to remove items one at a time (or using $in as mnemosyn suggested). Locking is short and fine-grained this way.